# Javascript How to replace part of a string using some of the text to be replaced

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

First off, I'm a javascript noob and know nearly nothing of regex. I'm trying to hack together something that would essentially change this:

```
<span class="fspoiler">spoils</span>
```

To this:

```
<spoiler>spoils</spoiler>
```

From some research, it would seem that using Regex and the `replace()` function are the way to go, but I don't where to start.

Comment: The tag name is the class name minus the 'f', right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var str = '<span class="fspoiler">spoils</span>';
str.replace(/<span class="f(.+)">(.+)<\/span>/, '<$1>$2</$1>');
```

Comment: Adding a `g` to the end of the regex would make this work across all instances in a string, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Was running into some issues when spoilers were encountered multiple times on the same line. Due to me being a noob at regex, I wasn't sure where to start in fixing it. I ended up just writing out a while block that would do what I needed.

```
var spoilerStart = '<span class="fspoiler">';
var spoilerEnd = '</span>';
while (body.indexOf(spoilerStart) != -1)
{
    var startIndex = body.indexOf(spoilerStart);
    var endIndex = body.indexOf(spoilerEnd, startIndex) + spoilerEnd.length;
    var fullSpoiler = body.substring(startIndex, endIndex);

    var textStartIndex = startIndex + spoilerStart.length;
    var textEndIndex = endIndex - spoilerEnd.length;
    var text = body.substring(textStartIndex, textEndIndex);

    body = body.replace(fullSpoiler, '<spoiler>' + text + '</spoiler>');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

by using jquery [replceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) function

```
$('span.fspoiler').replaceWith('<spoiler>spoils</spoiler>');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var className=document.getElementById("abc");
var tagName=className.replace("f","");
var content=document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML;
var newTag = "<"+tagName+">"+content+"<"+tagName"/>";
```

Here, assume that the `<span>` is given an `id="abc"`